# Prove confluence

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, rewriting-systems

I have these 2 questions to prove or disprove **confluence**.

**1)**

[image]

**Answer**

[image]

**2)**

[image]

**Answer**

[image]

Now I am having difficulty understanding these. Aren't these 2 questions same? then why in one case it is confluent and not in the other case. Please correct me and help me understand this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the questions are not the same.

The first one asks for a proof that every element has **at most** one normal form.

The second one asks for a proof that every element has **at least** one normal form.

If there may be an element with no normal form at all, then the second claim is wrong (but the first one still has a chance).

If there may be an element with two different normal forms, then the *first* claim is wrong, but there is still hope for the second one.

---

And, by the way, *neither* question asks you to "prove (or disprove) confluence". The questions *both* ask you to **assume as a given that $\succ$ is confluent** and then asks whether this or that is a *consequence* of this assumption.

Comment: Thank you for this. I got it now the difference between them. Can you explain me the answer how they prove the second one. I understand first one, but having difficulty in understanding the second prove. Thank you

Comment: @nobe: In the second question, the answer is _no, this is not true_. They prove that by giving an example of a $\succ$ that is confluent, but where at least one element of $A$ has no normal form.

Comment: but for this, can't i assume that a -> a1 and a -> a2 then there is b and then both a1 and a2 goes to a, then it is also confluent. what i am doing wrong here.

Comment: @nobe: Are you denying that the relation in the counterexample is confluent?

Comment: Yes, I am saying that if use the approach of prove 1, then what will be wrong there.

Comment: @nobe: I'm very confused now. It looks like in one of the same sentence you say that "yes", you are denying that the releation in the example solution to **question 2** is confluent (which is wrong; it _is_ obviously confluent), and then without even a full stop you're suddenly talking about **question 1** instead. ???

Comment: I am actually get confused sorry. I know both are confluent but one has at most one normal form and 2nd have at least one normal form. I want to ask, how can I prove the second one, with the approach of first proof.

Comment: @nobe: The first claim **is true**.  The second claim **is not true**. I don't see how you can even hope to use "the approach of the first proof" to answer something which is not true, and which therefore needs a counterexample rather than a proof.

Comment: ah ok, I got your point. I think my understanding is not good for this kind of questions. Can you refer me something where from I can learn this. Thank you again.

Comment: can you please explain me how to solve this one. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1892063/confluence-property-hold-or-not Thank you again. This is a confusing topic for me.